# lightweight Java api for writing excel file

Tags: java, excel

I need to create an excel file with simple text data. Concretely, it will allocate a list (one per cell) of email addresses. Data volume will be aprox 200000, so, I want to format it in, at least, 4 sheets (same book). This is because I need to be able to open the file in old Excel versions (max 65536 rows per sheet).

Due to simplicity of data (with no charts, neither functions, etc.), I can use many APIs. Few years ago I used **Apache POI** to manage excel files with nice results, but I think that is **too heavy** (1,7MB for version 3.7) and I want to know if there is other APIs less heavy.

Also, i would like it would be available in **Maven repository**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JExcelAPI](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl) is your friend here. All fully Mavenised and ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly an answer but [this page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0516.html) seems to have some good information in comparing the different solutions.  Gary's suggestion in JExcelAPI and ApachePOI are both presented along with a few more